# Unity creates two clones of an object, despite instantiate been called only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on some enemy AI in Unity, but when i try to instantiate a single projectile, it creates two in the exact same position. This happens even though instantiate is called once.

Instantiation code:

```
void Shoot(Vector3 direction){

    GameObject EnemyLaser = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("EnemyLaser"), FirePosition.transform.position, FirePosition.transform.rotation);
    EnemyLaser.renderer.material.color = gameObject.renderer.material.color;
    EnemyLaser.rigidbody.velocity = direction * laserPower;
}
```

Firing code:

```
void FireRaycast(){

    Vector3 direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * range);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, out hit, range)){

        if(hit.collider.tag == "Player"){

            if(currentTime > fireInterval){
                Shoot(direction);
                currentTime = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

}
```

This causes multiple issues, such as the two projectiles not moving because of their colliders, etc...

I've tried using booleans to check that the function is only called once but it still creates two objects.

Comment: [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) itself does already create an instance. Just take its return value

Comment: @Kay Using Resources.Load on a GameObject will get the reference to the prefab. But it will not instantiate it automatically.

Comment: @esa thanks for clearing this up, I haven't used Load with GameObjects but with TextAssets, images,... only

Comment: How often is FireRaycast called? Are you sure it's only being called once? What happens when you put a breakpoint in Shoot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem was solved, but this happened to me as well for a different reason than what has already been mentioned.

In my case I was using the [mouse click event](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) to generate objects in the environment. I was using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` and for some reason, this was returning `true` twice for each click thus creating two instances of my prefab.

The solution for me was to place a **time constraint** on how frequently new objects could be instantiated. After that, only one instance was created for each mouse click.